# convert mvc c# model class to json from datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, json.net

I have a C# class and data table.

DataTable:

```
+---------+-----------------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------+
| Pers_Id | Pers_First_Name | Pers_Last_Name| OrderNu | OrderId |  Pers_Update |
+---------+-----------------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------+
| 1       |       ABC       |        Ln     |   76454 |  1      |   2018-03-25 |
+---------+-----------------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------+
| 1       |       ABC       |        Ln     |   76578 |  2      |   2018-03-25 |
+---------+-----------------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------+
```

Class:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int Pers_Id { get; set; }
    public string Pers_First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Pers_Last_Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Pers_Update { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Order_List { get; set; }

    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public string OrderNu { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need to bind this class from data table and need to convert it into json object for rest API response in asp .net web API.

When i am binding i am getting json duplicate but result should be like this

{
  "Pers_Id": 1,
  "Pers_First_Name": "ABC",
  "Pers_Last_Name": "LN",
  "Pers_Update": "",
  "Order_List": [
    {
      "OrderID": "1",
      "OrderNu": "76454"
    },
    {
      "OrderID": "2",
      "OrderNu": "76578"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Just return the class object via the web api controller. By default the web api will convert the response to json

Comment: You can fill List<Person> from DataTable and use json.net to serialize the list.

Comment: @Marcus, but how to bind this , actually getting order_list null or duplicate

Answer (score 1):

When you have an object (f.eks. your Employee object in this example), you should be able to return it like this:

```
return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee), "application/json");
```

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34091196/4034346

Comment: thanks for answer but I know this actually I want to know how to bind this class with table and in json object I want distinct person with all his orders

Comment: hi @NiteeshKumar I assume your table is located in your application (and not in JSon object) cause you are trying to create a json object and send it from the data that is stored on your system, right?

Comment: In that case all you need to do is simply **get the instance of your Person object**. You can do that either **via Direct database call** (how to MSSQL DB call: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14172067/4034346), or via Entity Framework

Comment: I have a buisness layer and getting a data table from that and by looping I am setting the model value but getting duplicate records in json ..so I want to know the proper way of coding that how to set model by data table through looping and send back that model to response

Answer (score 0):

First;

> [using System.Web.Script.Serialization;](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Second;
If your data table's class isn't same with your Person class, then you should create a new class of datatable version for your persons.

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int Pers_Id { get; set; }
        public string Pers_First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Pers_Last_Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Pers_Update { get; set; }
        public List<Order> Order_List { get; set; }
        public class Order
        {
            public int OrderID { get; set; }
            public int OrderNu { get; set; }
        }
    }


    //You need a class that fits to your DataTable
    public class PersonDataTable
    {
        public int Pers_Id { get; set; }
        public string Pers_First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Pers_Last_Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Pers_Update { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int OrderNu { get; set; }
    }
```

In your method;

```
    public string ReturnGoodPeopleJsonFormat()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();//Needed for converting an object to Json string.
        List<PersonDataTable> personDataTableList = new List<PersonDataTable>();//Needed for filling your data from in program or from database
        List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();//Needed 'to be converted' in to Json string


        //Add items to your DataTable list manually
        personDataTableList.Add(
            new PersonDataTable { Pers_Id = 1, Pers_First_Name = "ABC", Pers_Last_Name = "Ln", Pers_Update = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-03-25"), OrderId = 1, OrderNu = 76454 });
        personDataTableList.Add(
            new PersonDataTable { Pers_Id = 1, Pers_First_Name = "ABC", Pers_Last_Name = "Ln", Pers_Update = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-03-25"), OrderId = 2, OrderNu = 76578 });

        //or from database
        // personDataTableList.AddRange(myDatabaseModel.DataTables.ToList());



        //Now group your data by Pers_Id //We are grouping this because we don't want same person 2 or 3 time, we want one person just one time but get all orders in it. That's why we need to group them by Pers_Id
        foreach (var personGroup in personDataTableList.GroupBy(x => x.Pers_Id))
        {
            List<Person.Order> orderList = new List<Person.Order>();

            foreach (var dataTablePerson in personDataTableList.Where(x => x.Pers_Id == personGroup.Key))
            {
                //Get all orders of personGroup one by one in to an Order list from PersonDataTable list by using Pers_Id like a foreign key.
                ///This personGroup.Key is nothing but Pers_Id\\\ 
                orderList.Add(new Person.Order { OrderID = dataTablePerson.OrderId, OrderNu = dataTablePerson.OrderNu });
            }

            //Add new Person object to your personList if you don't have it before (by checking Pers_Id)
            if (personList.Where(x => x.Pers_Id == personGroup.Key).Count() == 0) //This personGroup.Key is nothing but Pers_Id
            {
                personList.Add(new Person
                {
                    Pers_Id = personDataTableList.Where(x => x.Pers_Id == personGroup.Key).FirstOrDefault().Pers_Id,
                    Pers_First_Name = personDataTableList.Where(x => x.Pers_Id == personGroup.Key).FirstOrDefault().Pers_First_Name,
                    Pers_Last_Name = personDataTableList.Where(x => x.Pers_Id == personGroup.Key).FirstOrDefault().Pers_Last_Name,
                    Pers_Update = personDataTableList.Where(x => x.Pers_Id == personGroup.Key).FirstOrDefault().Pers_Update,
                    Order_List = orderList
                });
            }

        }
        string JsonString = js.Serialize(personList);
        return JsonString;
    }
```

The result is like this:

> [{"Pers_Id":1,"Pers_First_Name":"ABC","Pers_Last_Name":"Ln","Pers_Update":"/Date(1521925200000)/","Order_List":[{"OrderID":1,"OrderNu":76454},{"OrderID":2,"OrderNu":76578}]}]