# ASP.NET MVC Json.Net deserialize text/html json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net, restsharp

I post a api to get data, the response like json format, but the Content-Type was text/html

This is my code:

```
public ActionResult Test(string id)
{
    var request = GetMyRequest(id);
    RestClient client = new RestClient("baseUrl");
    var result = client.Execute(request).Content;
    var result2 = JObject.Parse(result);
    return Json(result2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I got the result

[image]

How can i deserialize the response correctly

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the content of `result` before deserialization.

Comment: Are you getting only square brackets in the JSON value?

Comment: Which version of asp.net-mvc are you using?  Up to 4.0 still uses `JavaScriptSerializer` which will not know how to serialize a `JObject`.  To switch to Json.NET see [Setting the Default JSON Serializer in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14591750) or [Using JSON.NET as the default JSON serializer in ASP.NET MVC 3 - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7109967).  Or try [Exception converting JSON.NET JObject to JsonResult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5572645) for a single method.

Comment: @dbc I use ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya if I create a model(class) to deserialize, it work correctly(not noly square brackets)

Comment: In that case I think we'll need more information, ideally an [mcve].  What is the content of the string `result`?

Comment: @Gary - I'm honestly not sure if MVC5 is using Json.NET by default or not. You might try doing return `Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result2), "application/json");` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19876131) to see if it fixes the problem. Or wait -- since result is **already** a string try `return Content(result, "application/json");`